# Magento advanced search form in sidebar

Tags: forms, search, magento

I'm using Magento 1.5.0.1 and I want to move my advanced search form to the sidebar for my 2columns-left template.

What I've tried was this:

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="catalogsearch/advanced_form" name="catalogsearch_advanced_form" template="catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

But unfortunately it doesnt show up.

When i browse to mywebsite/catalogsearch/advanced/ the form shows up in the sidebar so that goes well.

How can i change it so it always shows up in the sidebar?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you insert into your template:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalogsearch/advanced_form')->setTemplate('catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
```

Also pay attention that .js files are loaded for calendar.